# Marcar linhas onde soma do balanço = 0

Tags: postgresql

Tenho uma tabela como essa abaixo, com a data, num, valor de debito, valor de credito, e o valor do balanço (valor do debito + 0 - valor do credito) e preciso que cada vez que houver um valor de debito e de crédito e um mesmo numero de documento, que forem iguais, ou quando a soma do balanco for igual a zero.

Tentei fazer uma função mas só consegui sinalizar quando há dois registro com mesmo número e o resultado do balanço dá 0, que no exemplo abaixo seriam as linhas onde num = 219900. Porém queria sinalizar todos os que estão entre ** .

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

```
data        num     debito   credito      balanco   zero_balanco
11/11/2016  219900          470,00      -470,00     Y
11/11/2016  219900  470,00              470,00      Y

01/11/2016  218295  163,00              163,00    
30/11/2016  218295  162,00              162,00      **Y**
30/11/2016  218295  162,00              162,00      **Y**
30/11/2016  218295          162,00      -162,00     **Y**
30/11/2016  218295          162,00      -162,00     **Y**
30/11/2016  218295  162,00              162,00  

25/10/2016  218102  935,46              935,46      **Y**
25/10/2016  218102          935,46      -935,46     **Y**
25/10/2016  218102  935,46              935,46

20/10/2016  217638  1.896,65            1.896,65    **Y**   
20/10/2016  217638          1.896,65    -1.896,65   **Y**   
20/10/2016  217638  1.896,65            1.896,65    **Y**   
20/10/2016  217638          1.896,65    -1.896,65   **Y**   
20/10/2016  217638  1.696,65            1.696,65
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select data , num , sum(credito) credito , sum(debito) debito ,         sum(credito-debito) balance ,
(case when sum(credito-debito) = 0 then 's' else 'n' end) zero_balanco
from tabela
where ....
group by data , num
```

Creio ser isto , espero não estar simplificando

Comment: Infelizmente só isso não funciona...

Comment: Qual o problema ?

Comment: dessa forma, ele só sinaliza quando a diferença entre crédito e débito for zero... 
e ainda sim, eu tenho q estar independente da data, pois um lançamento debito no mês 10 pode ser creditado em datas/meses posteriores

Comment: Tirando a data do group by ?! select num , s ....group by  num